# Task Scheduler Prompt for Username & Password

Tags: powershell, task

I'm trying to use Powershell to create a Task Schedule to run a PS1 script.
eachtime the script is run I'd like the user to be prompted to enter the systems Username & Password (as this changes per system). Once the user has entered the systems credentials i'd like the script to enter that info into the Task Scheduler "Run as" parameter.

I've done some googling and learned how to prompt the user to enter text I've then told the script to lookup $Username and $SecurePassword for the info that was entered. This is the script so far..

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'cmd.exe' -Argument 'C:\VMStartup\VMHosts.bat'
$trigger1 =  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 00:00am
$Username = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Username"
$SecurePassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString 

Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger1 -TaskName VMCheck -Description Populates the VMHost CSV File -User $Username -Password $SecurePassword
```

Fixed it:

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'cmd.exe' -Argument 'C:\VMStartup\VMHosts.bat'
$trigger =  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 2am
$credential = Get-Credential
$username = $Credential.Username
$password = $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password

Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "VMStartup" -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -Description "Populates the VMHost CSV File" -User $username -Password $password
```

Comment: Try `Get-Credential` and save it in a variable.

Comment: Thanks Olaf, I'm pretty new to PS, could you advise how that would look in my script please?

Comment: I've tried:

```
$Creds = Get-Credential -credential $env:computername\$env:username


Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger1 -TaskName VMCheck -Description Populates the VMHost CSV File -User $Creds.Username -Password $Creds.GetNetworkCredential().Password
``` 

to no avail